# Error message if record exist is not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to check if record exist before it is inserted.  My code for checking is:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM firm WHERE ( name = '" . mysql_real_escape_string( $name ) . "' AND area = '" . mysql_real_escape_string( $areaname ) . "' )";
$rs = mysql_query( $query );

    if ( !$rs ) {
       echo "The firm for this area already exist.";
       trigger_error( mysql_error() );
    } else {
       echo "Saved.";
    }
```

My insert code is:

```
$result = array(); 
mysqli_autocommit( $dbc, FALSE );

$sql1 ="INSERT INTO `firm`(name, area, VAT, active) VALUES ('$name', '$areaname', '$VAT', '$active')"; 
//echo $sql1;
$result[] = mysqli_query( $dbc, $sql1 ) ;

$sql2 = "INSERT INTO `area`(name, hub_name, fk_hub_id) VALUES ('$areaname'
         ,(SELECT `name` from hub WHERE name = '$hub_name')
         ,(SELECT `id` from hub WHERE name = '$hub_name'))
        ";
//echo $sql2;
$result[] = mysqli_query($dbc,$sql2);       
$success = true;

if ( is_array( $results ) ) {
    foreach( $results as $result ) {
       if ( !$result ) {
           $success = false;
       }
    }
    if ( !$success ) {
       mysqli_rollback( $dbc );
    } else {
       mysqli_commit( $dbc );
    }
}
```

My problem is that my error message is not working.  When i submit my form and the record exist it says saved even though it is not inserted.  Can anybody tell me where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql_num_rows() to count your results.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM firm WHERE (name = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($name) . "' AND area = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($areaname) . "' )";
    $rs = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($query));

    if ($rs != 0) {
            echo "The firm for this area already exist.";
            trigger_error(mysql_error());
        }
    else {
     echo "Saved.";}
```

**Note that usage of mysql_* functions is deprectaded**

Have look on PDO

http://php.net/manual/de/book.pdo.php

And try porting your code on PDO as fast as possible.

Comment: She is using the mysqli functions in the insert code. But not in the method where she checks the record. heh.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has lots of spaghetti in it. take a look at PHP PDO extension. Reduces your lines by 90%.
Do not run PHP functions inline an SQL query.

Your query has an error. Remove the brackets from the variable names

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
$area = mysql_real_escape_string($areaname);

$query = "SELECT * FROM firm WHERE name = '$name' AND area = '$area'";
$rs = mysql_query($query);

if (!$rs) {
        echo "The firm for this area already exist.";
        trigger_error(mysql_error());
    }
else {
 echo "Saved.";
}
```